# Can cellphone magnetic holders affect the CPU?

Tags: magnetics, cellphone

My concern is mostly related to the various IC components such as CPU. I know that one of the problems of miniaturization is that electons jump to neighbouring lanes. Given how tight things are in an IC, a magnet would excite and strengthen the "jump" behaviour of the electrons.

How strong a magnet has to be to affect a CPU or other modern electronics components found in modern cell phones?
Is a casual car magnetic holder strong enough to stress the hardware (given it's attached directly to the casing - too close)

Comment: I have a Logitech magnetic case and magnet that I have been using for 4 years on my iPhone.  If you got really strong magnetic field, the first things to be affected would probably be any transformers (you might saturate the core) and possibly the haptic device (they are often a little motor with an off-center weight).  I think electrons would be way down the list.

Comment: short answer: no. maybe with an MRI-level field, but not a permanent magnet.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven not found any concrete evidence about it. So the only answer so far is with experimental data and that would be that IC do not suffer from small magnetic fields.

Concerning the down-vote, 
Down-voting withought giving an explicit reason in public you should get the down-voter banned and penalised. There is no room for trolling in stackexchange.